# puppet can't find module class from site.pp

Tags: puppet

I am new to puppet and I am strugling with error Couldn't find class profile::profileDev for ...

I am following profile/role abstraction for puppet. I have a module "profile" with defined classes:

```
class profile::baseNode($nodeId = undef){ some content}
```

Then I have class:

```
class profile::nodeB inherits baseNode{ ...}
```

In my site.pp

```
node 'puppetmaster.localdomain'{       

   class {'profile::nodeB':
    nodeId => 1,
   }
}
```

I have verified that "include profile" works. But I am unable to refer classes within module. Using puppet 2.7
Is there any obvious error I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that I've finally found the problem. It seems that the problem is the camelcasing in class names and filenames, as the following code works:
basenode.pp:

```
class profile::basenode($nodeId = undef){ some content}
```

nodeb.pp:

```
class profile::nodeB inherits baseNode{ ...}
```

In site.pp:

```
node 'puppetmaster.localdomain'{           
  class {'profile::nodeB':
     nodeId => 1,
   }
}
```